# Hide platform fee with PayPal Adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Our platform using PayPal Adaptive Payments with Chained Payment especially.

Default payment will look like this:
buyer make a transaction - money goes to a seller - platform takes fees
But in our application can be more than just one seller in a transaction.

In transaction can be more than one seller.

The problem here is that chained payment required only one Primary receiver and only this user will be responsible for pay fee to PayPal. How can we share this between our sellers and make sellers emails visible in receipt page without showing our platform?

Maybe we need another type of payments? Additional options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it sounds like you want to split the fees across each receiver instead of the primary receiver paying the entire fee..??

If I understand correctly, you could leave the Chained payment in place and add the FeesPayer=EACHRECEIVER to your Pay request.  So it would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PayRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
   <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
      <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
      <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
   </requestEnvelope>
   <actionType xmlns="">PAY_PRIMARY</actionType>
   <cancelUrl xmlns="">http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/cancel.php</cancelUrl>
   <clientDetails xmlns="">
      <applicationId>APP-80W284485P519543T</applicationId>
      <ipAddress>192.168.1.254</ipAddress>
   </clientDetails>
   <currencyCode xmlns="">USD</currencyCode>
   <feesPayer xmlns="">EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
   <receiverList xmlns="">
      <receiver>
         <amount>500.00</amount>
         <email>usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com</email>
         <primary>true</primary>
      </receiver>
      <receiver>
         <amount>50.00</amount>
         <email>sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com</email>
         <primary>false</primary>
      </receiver>
      <receiver>
         <amount>20.00</amount>
         <email>bogus@angelleye.com</email>
         <primary>false</primary>
      </receiver>
   </receiverList>
   <sender>
      <useCredentials xmlns="" />
   </sender>
   <account xmlns="">
      <phone />
   </account>
   <returnUrl xmlns="">http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/return.php</returnUrl>
</PayRequest>
```